# Angularjs ['ui-routing'] using different layout in parent as well as children

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frameworks, angular-ui-router

Lets say;
state: /profile (parent) i want to show 3 columns next to each other leftpane content rightpane

state /profile/{id} i want to show 2 columns leftpane and content.

i have worked this code out so far but its not really working the way i want it.

```
.state('test', {
  url: "/test",
          views:
          {
            "main":
             { 
                templateUrl:"app/views/templates/test/test.php",
                controller:function($scope, $stateParams)
                {
                 console.log("bum");
                 console.log($stateParams.id); //this is undefined even if i have it defined! 
                }
             }
          }

})
.state('test.id',
{
    url:"/{id}",
    views:{
        "main":{
            templateUrl:"app/views/templates/test/testOverWritten.php",
                controller:function($scope, $stateParams)
                {
                    console.log("main is overwritten");
                    console.log($stateParams.id);
                }
        },
        "testLeft":
        {
            templateUrl:"app/views/templates/test/test.menu.php",
            controller:function($scope)
            {
                console.log("insantieted");
            }
        },
        "testContent":
        {
            templateUrl:"app/views/templates/test/test.content.php",
            controller:function($scope)
            {
            console.log("insantieted");
            }
        }
    }
})
```

parent.index
has `<div ui-view="main"></div>`

test.php that is integrated into main.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div ui-view="testContent">Original</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div ui-view="testLeft">OrgMenu</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i should able to have different structure such as test.php to be integreted into main in order to show different layouts in different child states

Parent state layout is applied after a child state called by the url ( #/test/1 )
so the layout stays the same how do i change it or carry onto another template where chrildren can have different layouts?

Weird but solution was quite simple as i just discovered after 4 hours of research :(

```
.state('test.id',
{
    url:"/{id}",
    views:{
        "main@":{
            templateUrl:"app/views/templates/test/layout2.php",
                controller:function($scope, $stateParams)
                {
                    console.log("main is overwritten");
                    console.log($stateParams.id);
                }
        },
        "testMenu@test.id":
        {
            templateUrl:"app/views/templates/test/test.menu.php",
            controller:function($scope)
            {
                console.log("instantieted");
            }
        },
        "testContent@test.id":
        {
            templateUrl:"app/views/templates/test/test.content.php",
            controller:function($scope)
            {
            console.log("instantieted");
            }
        }
    }
})
```

i was directing views into wrong path, using viewname@statename brought a solution as explained in the link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

**Solved!**

Comment: It sounds like your two states do not share anything(besides url)?  Is that correct?

Comment: i am not passing any data for testing purposes just to make sure i am having the right structure. So yes only the urls and nested views @Nix